# Sound issue 14.04: Sound play through external soundcard but nothing in input/output sound setting

Tags: 14.04, sound

I am new to ubuntu and I have a sound issue that I'm browsing the web since two weeks trying to solve it.

Everything was working fine till I tried to use my everyman hd mic/headphone to use with skype. It did show in the output/input sound setting but did not worked. After a reboot I just lost everything in the sound settings but I can see every sound card available if I type alsamixer in the terminal. Sorry I cannot show any of my screenshot here since I don't have 10 reputation point :(

Here is what I have if I type aplay-l:

```
    jean-baptiste@jeanbaptiste-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: TonePortUX2 [TonePort UX2], device 0: TonePort UX2 [TonePort UX2]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Everyman [FREETALK Everyman], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

sudo lshw -C sound:

```
jean-baptiste@jeanbaptiste-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo lshw -C sound
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: GK107 HDMI Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
```

cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
jean-baptiste@jeanbaptiste-System-Product-Name:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

What I've done so far:

- Tried removing pulseaudio and installing alsa-mixer following these steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Line_Input.2BAC8-Microphone_Troubleshooting
- Upgraded Alsa following these steps: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Would be really cool if you can get me out of this! ;)

Jean-Baptiste

Answer (score 1):

Seems that everything went back to normal after redoing the steps at the end of the question ;)
If anyone has the same issue, try doing it too.

Thx